# How can I create an alternative to the F# Result type that doesn't take a type parameter for the Ok case?

Tags: f#

I normally use unit in situations where I don't need any data for the `Ok` case of a Result. `Result<unit,string>` for example. I have a situation now where the caller is an Orleans client and it's failing to serialize the unit type.

I've attempted to add my own version of `Result` that doesn't have a type parameter for `Ok` like so.

```ml
type Result<'E> =
| Ok
| Error of ErrorValue: 'E
```

However, the compiler is complaining about usages of the built in `Result` type now when a value is being assigned to `Ok`. The compiler still uses my new Result type even if I add an explicit return type annotation to the function.

I'll probably just rename my custom `Result` type to resolve this.

Is there some other technique that might allow me to overload this type the way I'm attempting to do it?

Comment: I would google Orleans and F# serializer/serialization for solutions to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example might help, but it sounds like you're doing this:

```ml
type Result<'E> =
| Ok
| Error of ErrorValue: 'E

let myFunc () : Result<int, string> =
    Ok 0   // compiler error: wrong Ok
```

You can fix this by using the full name of the `Ok` case:

```ml
let myFunc () : Result<int, string> =
    FSharp.Core.Ok 0
```

If it's a hassle to do that each time, you can also open the FSharp.Core namespace beforehand:

```ml
open FSharp.Core

let myFunc () : Result<int, string> =
    Ok 0
```